# Go to next screen after save data xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to go next screen after the save button is pushed, i tried to write code perform segue and i get buch of errors. Below is my code currently, i didn't finish the save part. I wanted to go back to that later time.

I'm new to coding in xcode, so any advice on where to put this code would be nice.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SignupVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var txtfirstname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtlastname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtConfirmpassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtEmail: UITextField!

var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func signupTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        _ = txtUsername.text;
        _ = txtPassword.text;
        _ = txtConfirmpassword.text;
        _ = txtEmail.text;


        //check empty fields
        if((txtPassword.text?.isEmpty)! || (txtConfirmpassword.text?.isEmpty)! || (txtEmail.text?.isEmpty)!)
        {

         //Display alert
            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required")
            return;
        }
        //check if passwords match
        if (txtPassword.text != txtConfirmpassword.text)

        {
            //Display in alert message
            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords don't match");
            return;
        }
        //store Data

        // Display alert message with Confirmation
    }
        func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
        {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil);

            myAlert.addAction(okAction);

            self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);

}
    /*
```

Answer (score 0):

just go into storyboard and hold control key on the button and let it go on the ViewController you want to go to. Then select the kind. For Example "Show"

then it should work. If you have questions ask.

Comment: Problem is i have rules for that button, like if the password is empty. I'm sure i could put another if statement in there. But i'm not sure if its suppose to go after fun display or do i need completely have separate call for this.